# Server errors using php/soap/lighttpd

Tags: php, soap, lighttpd

I am using buildroot to build an image and put it on a switch. I enabled lighttpd/soap/php but I get an error when I try to run the web interface. A normal php test file works find. I had this web interface working fine on another system, I know the code is fine. SO it is a configuration issue.

Here is the error I receive:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://127.0.0.1:18083/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/library.php on line 35

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1:18083/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl" in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/library.php on line 35

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/library.php:35) in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/library.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function __soapCall() on a non-object in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/library.php on line 71
```

Configuration from php.info:

```
'./configure' '--target=arm-linux' '--host=arm-linux' '--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--disable-gtk-doc' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-all' '--without-pear' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-soap' '--enable-simplexml' '--disable-cli' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-fastcgi' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-posix' '--enable-spl' '--enable-session' '--with-openssl=/home/buildmaster/svn_main_vm/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr' '--enable-libxml' '--with-libxml-dir=/home/buildmaster/svn_main_vm/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-zlib=/home/buildmaster/svn_main_vm/buildroot/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr'
```

Here is an error log:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.2605) FastCGI-stderr: ---------Filename: 127.0.0.1:18083/SoftCo
reSOAP.wsdl
(mod_fastcgi.c.2605) FastCGI-stderr: NULL client
```

Here is the full php.info

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxjdh6g2wc9eb04/Untitled%20Document.htm

Any ideas on what I have not configured correctly?

EDIT: so basically port 18083 is closed, but the application should have opened it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access the WSDL file (`http://127.0.0.1:18083/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl`) you get the Warning (2nd line) - in the next ten lines the library.php writes something to the output stream and so the headers are sent to the client - then you want to modify the header on line 45
Error and things gone bad ;)

So try to make the wsdl access able

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this, it sounds like some permissions issue and nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: I dont know how to, it is located on the switch. I tried 192.168.1.1:18082/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl and no page displayed

Comment: hmm... than you have to provide the wsdl in a other way (add it to your php files,...)

Comment: If I go to 192.168.1.1:80/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl it shows me all the code for the wsdl file

Comment: is it an issue with the port?

Comment: yeah... you can try to change the WSDL url to `http://127.0.0.1:80/SoftCoreSOAP.wsdl` or configure lighttpd so that it listens on 18083

Comment: Neither work, just give different errors. i know this was working without changing ports a few days ago.